# How can I change the values in XAML based on user input from a textBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

How can I change the values in XAML based on user input from a textBox? I'm just starting off with WPF/Silverlight and like what most people say, there is a steep learning curve. In the code below I get the result in the picture below.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="250">
   <Span FontSize="20">2</Span>
   <Span BaselineAlignment="TextTop" FontSize="14">1/2</Span>
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

But I want the fraction to be the result of a computation. Not static like above. Is it possible to take the value of something computed in a .cs file, and add that value as a variable to the XAML file.

Any answers or points in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look (*- actually one look will not be enough -*) at [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), you can create a property which holds the value of the fraction and bind the text to that. If you want actual factions like `1/2` you will probably need a proper struct with an approriate `ToString` override.

Answer (score 0):

Use Binding, as H.B. suggested.  The end result will look similar to the code snippet below.

```
<Span Foreground="Gray">
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=yourPath}"/>
</Span>
```